# Redirect all requests to subdirectory without changing the url _and_ remove subdirectory from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

For a seamless deployment of new website versions I'm using following directives to transparently redirect all requests to a specific subdirectory (`v2` in this snippet).

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !v2/
RewriteRule (.*) /v2/$1 [L]
```

The next step is, that I need another rewrite rule to ensure, that requests to that subdirectory will be redirected the corresponding root url (e.g. `https://example.com/v2/foo.html` should redirect to `https://example.com/foo.html`).

All my attempts in creating this rule by myself resulted in an redirect loop.